# How to write unit test for azure function (Httptrigger) with ILogger

Tags: dependency-injection, nunit, azure-functions, mstest, azure-functions-runtime

Want to write unit test for HttpTrigger GET.
Have method signature as follow:

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = null)]
    HttpRequestMessage request, 
    ILogger log)
```

here, `ILogger` is type of Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.

How to write unit test case with this injection,
Tried to create stub of `ILogger` using below stuff but this needs `LoggerFactory`.

```
public class LoggerWriter : Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Logger<ILogger>
{
    public LoggerWriter() : base() // this needs logger factory.
    {
    }
}
```

Any sample unit test for httptrigger azure function to overcome above issue (`Ilogger` injection) is helpful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There really is no need to extend an implementation concern when the subject method requires an abstraction that can be easily mocked and injected.

Take following simplified example

```cs
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = null)]
    HttpRequestMessage request, 
    ILogger log
) {
    //...omitted for brevity
}
```

To unit test the above function in isolation, simply provide the necessary dependencies for the test to be exercised to completion and assert the expected behavior.

```cs
[TestMethod]
public async Task Function_Should_Return_Desired_Response() {
    //Arrange
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage();
    //...populate as needed for test

    var logger = Mock.Of<ILogger>(); //using Moq for example
    //...setup expected behavior

    //Act
    var response = await MyFunction.Run(request, logger);

    //Assert
    //...assert desired behavior in the response 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There's a great blog post that covers this topic :)
https://medium.com/@jeffhollan/serverless-devops-and-ci-cd-part-1-f76f0357cba4